# Hardware security key with locked down usb slots

Tags: yubikey, u2f, fido

I would like to use hardware security keys in an environment where it is additionally needed to lock down any ways in which a user could download data to a device like a usb key. Is it possible to lock down a usb slot in a way, that file transfer is not possible but hardware security keys still work?

In my case the scenario would include Windows 10 Pro as an OS and preferably a fido2 capable key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It will reduce security, but may still be good enough.

U2F devices appear as a [HID device](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-ps-20141009/fido-u2f-hid-protocol-ps-20141009.html). That's a USB class for keyboards and mice. USB storage devices appear as USB storage devices.

You can disable one class in your OS, e.g. [disable USB storage](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2017/06/27/prevent-the-use-of-usb-media-in-windows-10.aspx) (and UAS), but allow HID.

Comment: There are also endpoint agents that can help with managing this.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to attach the security key permanently. This still keeps most of the benefits of the security key defending against phishing or credential stuffing.

- Gluing the key into an external USB slot will allow using keys which require the user to press a button on the key, but will make the key impossible to replace if broken (or after a recall like the recent Yubikey FIPS key recall)
- Attaching the key to a USB header on the motherboard (and locking the case shut) will allow replacing a broken key but means that you will have to use a key that works without a button press, which is slightly less secure due to not requiring user confirmation.

Comment: Embedding the security key in the device negates many of the security benefits of using one.

Comment: It reduces the set of possible attackers from "anyone on the internet" to "anyone with physical access to the device". Admittedly the requirement "lock down ways in which a user could download data to USB" implies that not all people with physical access are trusted, but at least the threat has been reduced.